# How to add colors for Charts in Numbers v6

Tags: numbers, color, graph

Numbers 6.2.1 limits you to six colors for a Chart, which is a problem when creating a donut chart with more than six segments. Is there a way to add colors if needed?

I've found this question being answered for earlier versions of Numbers, but  it's unclear how to do it in v6.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clearer. Or so I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I just filled  2 columns and 12 lines in a spreadsheet. I then made a donut chart as shown in the image below.

[image]

The chart needed more than 6 colors so some colors were repeated. I clicked on the chart once to select it and then clicked again on a colored segment. See next image

[image]

You can see here that I have selected one of the colored segments and slightly separated it.  Now I go to the Style tab at the top right of the Numbers file. You can see here where you can change the color of the segment. I changed one instance of light blue to bright blue, one instance of green to a dull green, one instance of gold to yellow and finally one instance of red to fusia. This final plot is shown below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good recommendation but I still see only 6 types of colors in your chart if I am not mistaken. The OP seems to be how to have more than 6 colors in a chart when you have more than six segments.

Comment: @Alper It looks like the picture jmh posted was BEFORE he recolored. I think this is the right answer, but needs to be clearer. The process: Click once to select entire chart; click again on the segment you wish to re-color; switch to the Style tab in the Format pane; expand the Fill section to reveal pickers for the kind of fill (Color fill, Gradient fill, etc.). Choose Color fill, then click the color picker icon, which brings up the standard Apple color picker (crayons, RGB sliders, etc.), and choose any color you want.

Comment: Yes, the image shown was before I replaced the repeated colors. i'll add more to my answer.

Comment: Sorry if that is the case and thx for more detailed instructions but from what I have tried on Numbers 6.2.1, the directions @jmh or you have shared are unable to bring in more than six colors to a chart at the same time. When I follow these instructions, Numbers simply change colors for all the same colored segments and, albeit different from the first set, one ends up still having only six colors in the chart even if there are more than six segments. Thx.

Comment: Thx for the update. Here is what I think is missing from or unclear in your or @Chap's directions. If one has more than six segments in a chart and would like to have more than six colors accordingly, s/he needs to recolor the 7th or 8th, etc. segment to get more than six colors. If s/he recolors any of the first six segments the first time, then, unfortunately, the color for the "corresponding" segment in the next six (1st & 7th, or 3rd & 9th) is also changed the same.

Comment: No, in my image I changed 4 colors to new different colors and they show up that way in the last image of my answer.  See the 4th image in my answer and compare it to the 1st image

Comment: Thx but I have already tested the “feature” I described (1st&7th etc., probably a bug) on two different Macs and at least that’s how it seems to work on the Numbers v6.2 apps I have. In addition, by comparing the before and after pictures you have shared and also looking at the colors in the after-picture, you seem to have changed only some of the colors starting with the 7th segment (those starting with 12% clockwise) whereas the colors in the first 6 segments (those starting with 1%) seem to be the standard ones and unchanged from the before picture.

Comment: I also have to mention that once, for example, the 7th or 9th segment is recolored, it seems that the links between the 1st & 7th or 3rd & 9th segments are broken and one can then also recolor 1st or 3rd segments without also changing the 7th or 9th segments, respectively. Hope these help.